# Thymeleaf, Spring Boot 2: invalid path to resources when handle error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot Thymeleaf app with default settings:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect")
```

Problem is in **invalid path to resources in some cases** when handle error and as a result app can't show resoures (css/js/image) on page.

Path to resoures: `/src/main/resources/static/assets`

For logging path I made `RequestInterceptor`. It logs the part of request's URL.

I describe 4 cases. Paths and logs in interceptor:

1. calling the correct path `/home` - all work fine

> ```
> [09:02:48.759][INFO] /home
> [09:02:48.759][INFO] /assets/img/java60.png
> ```

2. calling the incorrect path `/first` (expect 404 error) - all work fine

> ```
> [09:02:48.759][INFO] /first
> [09:02:48.777][INFO] /error
> [09:02:49.589][INFO] /assets/css/simple.css
> [09:02:49.590][INFO] /assets/img/notFound.png
> [09:02:49.715][INFO] /favicon.ico
> ```

3. calling the incorrect path `/first/second` (expect 404 error) - unexpected behavior

> ```
> [09:03:00.390][INFO] /first/second
> [09:03:00.395][INFO] /error
> [09:03:00.422][INFO] /first/assets/css/simple.css
> [09:03:00.422][INFO] /first/assets/img/notFound.png
> [09:03:00.426][INFO] /error
> [09:03:00.426][INFO] /error
> ```

4. calling the incorrect path `/first/second/third` (expect 404 error) - unexpected behavior

> ```
> [09:39:06.404][INFO] /first/second/third
> [09:39:06.409][INFO] /error
> [09:39:06.441][INFO] /first/second/assets/css/simple.css
> [09:39:06.441][INFO] /first/second/assets/img/notFound.png
> [09:39:06.446][INFO] /error
> [09:39:06.446][INFO] /error
> ```

In third and fourth cases app redirects to error and set up path (request's URL + path to assets on page). Why spring make invalid path to resources in 3 and 4 cases?

The complete source code is available over on [Github](https://github.com/MaximDzhezhelo/spring-thymeleaf-example.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link resources using an absolute path. Currently, you are linking using relative paths like `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{assets/css/simple.css}">`.

Try to update your resources to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/css/simple.css}">
<img th:src="@{/assets/img/java60.png}" sizes="16x16" alt="love">
```